# Large difference in performance of complex SQL query executed as View in MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, view, query-optimization

Is there any general explanation why an SQL query performs much worse when it is executed encapsulated in a View than when it is executed as a normal query?

It all started when a view that included a query of a certain complexity showed bad performance, so I began to analyze what could be causing that result.

I did a test creating the view and executing a SELECT-WHERE on the view and another test executing the same SELECT-WHERE embedding the text of the view in the FROM part. Here's an idea of ​​the tests.

Test # 1

```
CREATE VIEW V AS
SELECT <DEF>
WHERE <EXPR>
GO

SELECT * FROM V WHERE <EXPR2>
GO
```

Excutes in 20+ minutes

Test # 2

```
SELECT V.*
FROM ( SELECT <DEF>
    WHERE <EXPR> ) V
WHERE <EXPR2>`
```

Executes in less than 1 minute

Comment: Without seeing the actual query and the table schemas it's impossible to say. Have you examined the actual execution plans for each? What did you notice about their differences?

Comment: Views can be expensive.  One option is a Table-Valued Function.   You can pass parameters (filters) and reduce the number of touchpoints.

Comment: Using a view can, depending on the way a query is constructed, prevent certain optimisations the optimizer might otherwise be able to take advantage of, for example pushing a filter predicate down to the storage IO instead of reading more rows and then filtering at a later point in the plan.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM V WHERE <EXPR2>` may just be a victim of parameter sniffing and when you change to the derived table you get a newly compiled plan that isn't. Again this is something you need to look at execution plans to see.

Comment: This is a long shot, but if your definition or expression uses a linked server references, the execution plan might not be able to use predicate pushdowns in the view, but could when the expression is completely encapsulated.